# How to filter based off multiple values?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter a character array so that it doesn't include blank spaces or periods. Why would the following code not work?

```
arr.filter(char => char !== ' ' || char !== '.')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `and (&&)`, not `or (||)`.

```
arr.filter(char => char !== ' ' && char !== '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use multi condition to express our idea, it produces bug more easily. In your case, using a filer_array is good idea, plain and more maintainable:

```
let filter_array = [' ', '.']
let arr = Array.from(' .test. ')
arr.filter(char => !filter_array.includes(char))
```